# add filename to beginning of file using find and sed

Tags: shell, sed, find

using the following I add the file name to the front of each line and send the output to a single file.

```
ls | while read file; do sed -e "s/^/$file/g" $file > out; done
```

I want to perform the same `sed` replacement but using a `find` and `exec` or `xargs`  command -

```
find . -type f -exec sed "s/^/{}/g" {} > out +
```

but I get an error -

> find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... +

Input files are like this -

fileA.txt

```
A1
A2
```

fileB.txt

```
B1
B2
```

desired output

```
fileA.txt A1
fileA.txt A2
fileB.txt B1
fileB.txt B2
```

**I know how to do this with awk, but I'd like to do it with sed, find and exec or xargs.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 find . -type f |xargs awk '$0=FILENAME$0' > out
```

as I answered this, your "no awk" line not yet there. anyway, take a look my updated answer below:

**updated based on comment**

so you want to use find, exec/xargs, and sed to do it. My script needs **GNU Sed**, i hope you have it.

see the one liner first: (well, `> out` is omitted. You could add it to the end of the line. )

```
find . -type f | xargs -i echo {}|sed -r 's#(.\/)(.*)#cat &\|sed  "s:^:file \2 :g"#ge'
```

now let's take a test, see below:

```
kent$  head *.txt
==> a.txt <==
A1
A2

==> b.txt <==
B1
B2

kent$  find . -type f | xargs -i echo {}|sed -r 's#(.\/)(.*)#cat &\|sed  "s:^:file \2 :g"#ge'
file b.txt B1
file b.txt B2
file a.txt A1
file a.txt A2
```

is the result your expectation?

**Short explanation**

- `find ....|xargs -i echo {}` nothing to explain, just print the
  filename per line (with leading `"./"`)
- then pass the filename to a sed line like `sed -r 's#(.\/)(.*)# MAGIC
  #ge'`
- remember that in the above line, we have two groups `\1: "./"` and
  `\2 "a.txt"(filename)`
- since we have `e` at the end of sed line, the **MAGIC** part would be
  executed as shell command.(GNU sed needed)
- **MAGIC**: `cat &\|sed  "s:^:file \2 :g`  cat & is just output the file
  content, and pipe to another sed. do the replace (`s:..:..:g`)
- finally, the execution result of MAGIC would be the Replacement of
  the outer sed.

the key is the 'e' of Gnu sed.

Comment: As I said in the question, I know how to do this with awk, but I'd like to do it with sed and find.

Comment: thanks, if you the time and interest, could you add some explanatory comments?

Comment: explanation was added in answer.

Comment: @Bryan: I'm curious: How is the performance of this solution on your data?

Comment: Very slow. My awk solution is what I'm using.

Answer (score 6):

untested, try using xargs

```
find . -type f | xargs -I FILE sed "s/^/FILE/g" FILE > out
```

Comment: changing '/' to '|' worked for me.  
`find . -type f | xargs -I FILE sed "s|^|FILE|g" FILE > out`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply replace the `ls` in your first line with the `find` like this?

```
find . -type f | while read file; do sed -e "s|^|$file|" $file > out; done
```

You must only exchange the delimiter for `s`  from `/` to something else not contained in your filenames. I have chosen `|` as an example.

Comment: from what I can see find with -exec is much faster and I have tens of thousands of files.

Comment: @Bryan: Performance has not been mentioned so far. And since both `find -exec` and the `while` loop will create a new `sed` process for each file you neither gain nor loose something. Further: I expect, that the most time will be spent reading and writing the _contents_ of the files.

Comment: FYI for a small number of files -  time find . -type f -exec sed "s/^/replacement/g" {} + takes real 0m0.736s but time find . -type f | while read file; do sed -e "s|^|replacement|" $file ; done takes real    0m3.165s. and using xargs instead of exec is a tiny bit faster

Comment: @Bryan: For a _constant_ `replacement` you are right. But that's not what was asked in the question. The question wants _variable_ replacement - variable per file. Therefore one `sed` call per file is required. So you cannot use neither `find|xargs` nor `find -exec +`.

Answer (score 1):

this one works fine for me and it is simpler to use than Kent's answer

NOTE: than the full pathname is inserted for that one

```
find . -type f | xargs -r -t -i sed -r 's|^|'{}' |g' {}
```

use this one instead to keep only the bare filename part

```
find . -type f | xargs -r -t -i sed -r -e 's|^|'{}' |g' -e 's|^.+/||g' {}
```

then if your are happy with stdout results you might add **-i** switch to the sed command to overwrite the files

```
find . -type f | xargs -r -t -i sed -i -r -e 's|^|'{}' |g' -e 's|^.+/||g' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find . -type f | xargs -i echo FILE/{} > out
```

Comment: Can you amend your question to show an example of what kind of output you want? I don't quite understand as it is currently written.