# loop that prepends the filename to the beginning of each line in a tab separated file (thus generating a new column))

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm pretty new at this and try to loop over around 19000 files (all in one dir) in order to insert at the  beginning of each line in each file the corresponding filename.

I will later concatenate these files to get a file containing all the data i need for my analyses.

File names show the following pattern:

`V_foo_V_bar`
The two `V_` parts in each filename are constant. the rest varies.

I tried:

```
for f in V*; do awk '{print "$f" $} file
```

I did this with and without parentheses around `$f` and both didn't work.

With parentheses the string `$f` is inserted to the file name 
Without paretheses nothing is inserted

Help would be very much appreciated since I already tried a couple of other equally futile ideas of mine and frustration knocking on my door

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate [add filename to beginning of file using find and sed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7812497)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To insert filename at the begining of each line of each file, try something like:

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' V*
```

`FILENAME` is a built-in variable that carries the name of the file. 
`V*` will glob to all the files in your directory.

If you wish to put a separator between the name and lines you can do:

```
awk '{print FILENAME " : " $0}' V*
```

Comment: crazy fast editing and very nice solution thanks a lot

Comment: I voted up even though you edited the "may the force be with you" out. that's how thankfull I am :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for f in V*; do sed -i "s/^/$f\t/" "$f"; done
```

This assumes that no filenames have awkward characters such as `*`. Spaces should be ok, though.

Comment: ***Edit:*** If your `sed` does not support the `-i` switch, you'll need to add `mv $f $f.bak`, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jaypal, it solved a similar problem I had. I amended your answer to add the filename and concat the file

```
awk '{print FILENAME " : " $0}' V* >> all.csv
```