# Add filename to output of an xargs and awk command

Tags: shell, awk, xargs

I have a directory full of .txt files, each of which has two columns and many rows (>10000). For each of these files, I am trying to find the maximum value in the second column, and print the corresponding entry in columns 1 and 2 to an output file. For this, I have a working awk command.

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs -I FILE awk '{if(max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1}}END{print datum, max}' FILE >> out.txt
```

However, I would also like to print the name of the corresponding input file with each pair of numbers. The output would look something like:

> file1.txt datum1 max1
>   file2.txt datum2 max2

For this, I tried to draw inspiration from this similar question:
[add filename to beginning of file using find and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812497/add-filename-to-beginning-of-file-using-find-and-sed),
but I couldn't quite get a working solution. My best effort so far looks something like this

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs -I FILE echo FILE | awk '{if(max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1}}END{print datum, max}' FILE >> out.txt
```

but I get the error:

> awk: can't open file FILE
>   source line number 1

I tried various other approaches which are probably a few characters away from being correct:
(1)

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs -I FILE -c "echo FILE ; awk '{if(max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1}}END{print datum, max}' FILE" >> out.txt
```

(2)

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c "echo {} && awk '{if(max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1}}END{print datum, max}' {}" \; >> out.txt
```

I don't mind what command is used (xargs or exec or whatever), I only really care about the output.

Comment: You say you have a directory *"full"* of files - how many is that roughly please?

Comment: approximately 10,000 files, and the number of rows per file is approximately 100,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the .txt files are in the current directory, try (GNU awk):

```
awk '{if(max=="" || max<$2+0){max=$2;datum=$1}}ENDFILE{print FILENAME, datum, max; max=""}' *.txt
```

If you want to search both the current directory and all its subdirectories for .txt files, then try:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk '{if(max=="" || max<$2+0){max=$2;datum=$1}}ENDFILE{print FILENAME, datum, max; max=""}' {} +
```

Because modern `find` has an `-exec` action, the command `xargs` is rarely needed anymore.

#### How it works

- `{if(max=="" || max<$2+0){max=$2;datum=$1}}`

  This finds the maximum column 2 and saves its and the corresponding value in column 1.
- `ENDFILE{print FILENAME, datum, max; max=""}`

  After the end of each file is reached, this prints the filename and column 1 and column 2 from the line with the maximum column 2.

  Also, at the end of each file, `max` is reset to an empty string.

#### Example

Consider a directory with these three files:

```
$ cat file1.txt
1       1
2       2
$ cat file2.txt
3       12
5       14
4       13
$ cat file3.txt
1       0
2       1
```

Our command produces:

```
$ awk '{if(max=="" || max<$2+0){max=$2;datum=$1}}ENDFILE{print FILENAME, datum, max; max=""}' *.txt
file1.txt 2 2
file2.txt 5 14
file3.txt 2 1
```

#### BSD awk

If we cannot use ENDFILE, try:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1{print f, datum, max; max=""} max=="" || max<$2+0{max=$2;datum=$1;f=FILENAME} END{print f, datum, max}' *.txt
file1.txt 2 2
file2.txt 5 14
file3.txt 2 1
```

Because one awk process can analyze many files, this approach should be fast.

- `FNR==1 && NR>1{print f, datum, max; max=""}`

  Every time that we start a new file, we print the maximum from the previous file.

  In awk, `FNR` is the line number of the current file and `NR` is the total number of lines read so far.  When `FNR==1 && NR>1`, that means that we have finished at least one file and we are started on the next.
- `max=="" || max<$2+0{max=$2;datum=$1;f=FILENAME}`

  Like before, we capture the maximum of column 2 and the corresponding datum from column 1.  We also record the filename as variable `f`.
- `END{print f, datum, max}`

  After we finish reading the last file, we print its maximum line.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for ENDFILE.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and explanation! I particularly like the or statement.

Comment: It seems I have to replace ENDFILE with END for this to do anything, and then it will work on a single file only before stopping. As Ed Morton noted, this command requires GNU awk. I should have stated I'm on OS X using zsh, and presumably don't have GNU awk. Is there an appropriate modification?

Comment: @user9186266 Sorry about that!  I have added a BSD-friendly version to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 10,000 files of 100,000 lines each, you will be quite a long time waiting if you start a new invocation of `awk` for each and every file like this because you will have to create 10,000 processes:

```
find . -name \*.txt -exec awk ....
```

I created some test files and found that the above takes just over 5 minutes on my iMac.

So, I decided to see what all those lovely *Intel* cores and all that lovely flash disk that I paid *Apple* so dearly for might be able to do using **GNU Parallel**.

Basically, it will run as many jobs in parallel as your CPU has cores - probably 4 or 8 on a decent Mac, and it can tag output lines with the parameters it supplied to the command:

```
parallel --tag -q awk 'BEGIN{max=$2;d=$1} $2>max {max=$2;d=$1} END{print d,max}' ::: *.txt
```

That produces the same results and now runs in 1 minute 22 seconds, nearly a 4x speedup, - not bad! But we can do better... as it stands above, we are still invoking a new `awk` for every file, so 10,000 `awks`, but in parallel, 8 at a time. It would be better to pass as many files as the OS permits to each of our 8 `awk`s that run in parallel. Luckily, **GNU Parallel** will work out how many that is for us, with the `-X` option:

```
parallel -X -q gawk 'BEGINFILE{max=$2;d=$1} $2>max {max=$2;d=$1} ENDFILE{print FILENAME,d,max}' ::: *.txt
```

That now takes 49 seconds, but note that I am using `gawk` for `ENDFILE`/`BEGINFILE` and not the `--tag` option because each awk invocation is now receiving many hundreds of files rather than just one.

---

**GNU Parallel** and **gawk** can be easily installed on a Mac with **homebrew**. You just go to the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and copy and paste the one-liner into your terminal. Then you have a proper package manager on macOS and access to thousands of quality, useful, well managed packages.

Once you have **homebrew** installed, you can install **GNU Parallel** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

and you can install **gawk** with:

```
brew install gawk
```

---

If you don't want a package manager, it's worth noting that **GNU Parallel** is just a **Perl** script and macOS ships with **Perl** anyway. So, you can also install it very simply with:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ ) | bash
```

---

Note that if your filenames are longer than about 25 characters, you will hit the limit of 262,144 characters on the argument length and get an error message telling you the argument list is too long. If that happens, just feed the names on `stdin` like this:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 | parallel -0 -X -q gawk 'BEGINFILE{max=$2;d=$1} $2>max {max=$2;d=$1} ENDFILE{print FILENAME,d,max}'
```

Comment: This does indeed give a remarkable speed-up. The filenames I have are typically 40 characters, but as you say that is no problem when feeding via stdin. I didn't check whether stdin feed affects speed, but it's fast enough not to care.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -n 1 -I FILE awk '(FNR==1) || (max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1} END{print FILENAME, datum, max}' FILE >> out.txt

find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk '(FNR==1) || (max<$2){max=$2;datum=$1} END{print FILENAME, datum, max}' {} \; >> out.txt
```

(edited by OP for typo)